# Perform actions on dynamic created div using the ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, dynamic, stringbuilder

How do I perform actions (e.g change text) when I know the ID of the div that I created dynamically with this code:

```
Stringbuilder sb = new Strinbuilder();
sb.AppendLine("<div id='example'>I want to change this text</div>");

//Examples using a literal, placeholder or a lable:

litExample.Text = sb.ToString();

phExample.Text = sb.ToString();

lblExample.Text = sb.ToString();



//Call id example and change "I want to change this text" , to something else.
//How do I do this?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically - you don't in that manner. You can create a HTMLGenreric Control and add that to your page, which might do what you're trying to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. But you're not really providing enough information to give more advice/help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Of All make sure you have added following namespaces:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
```

and add following method to your code:

```
  public string RenderControl(Control ctrl)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

        ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

and change your code to following:

```
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        HtmlGenericControl myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        myDiv.InnerText = "I want to change this text";

        //Make sure asp.net does not add any prefix to your Id "example"
        myDiv.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
        myDiv.ID = "example";

        //Examples using a literal, placeholder or a lable:

        litExample.Text = RenderControl(myDiv);

        phExample.Text = RenderControl(myDiv);

        lblExample.Text = RenderControl(myDiv);

        //Do Stuff with myDiv as typical control
```

Answer (score 2):

When the page has already been rendered, you might want to do this with javascript. Something like:

```
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = 'New text';
```

If the page has not been rendered yet, you probably need to adjust the string directly inside your stringbuilder, or at each instance where you use it, or maybe use a different approach altogether, but you don't provide enough information in your question to say anything useful about that.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little thing, you're gonna have a bad time with JS since all your DIVs share the same ID...

You could solve the problem by setting the IDs manually AND setting the **ClientIDMode** on *Static* to prevent an automatic creation as pointed by Seyed.

You could use a custom CSS class to select all the items at once.

Comment: +1 for your note. Yes your right. But his source code has this problem. It's up to him how to generate id.

Comment: True, I saw the generation part after posting my initial answer. Thanks ^^